# Method headers allowed by the compiler (simple Java exercise)

Tags: java

I am practicing and the simple exercise is, given a FeatureFilm class defined to have the following methods:

```
public void update(Actor a, String title)
public void update(Actor a, Actor b, String title)
public void update(String topic, String title)
```

which of the following additional method headers would be allowed by the compiler?

```
public boolean update(String category, String theater)
public boolean update(String title, Actor a)
public void update(Actor b, Actor a, String title)
public void update(Actor a, Actor b)
```

So I did the code and the compiler doesn't allow this methods: `public boolean update(String category, String theater)` and `public void update(Actor b, Actor a, String title)`, but I don't entirely understand why. Someone could explain this to me please?
I hope to be making good use of this site. I'm a OPP beginner.
Sorry about my (poor) English,
Thanks.

Comment: [Here you go](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: How can compiler choose between `public void update(String topic, String title)` and `public boolean update(String category, String theater)` ?
Or between `public void update(Actor a, Actor b, String title)` and `public void update(Actor b, Actor a, String title)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *signature* of a method in Java is made up of the number, type, and order of arguments, but *not* the return type.

**Not allowed:**

```
public boolean update(String category, String theater)
public void update(Actor b, Actor a, String title)
```

These methods have the same signature as ones which already appear, and the return type does not determine the signature.  The trick here is that even though the return types are different, the signatures are still the same.

**Allowed:**

```
public boolean update(String title, Actor a)
public void update(Actor a, Actor b)
```

These methods have different signatures from the ones which already appear, because the type and order of parameters are different.

Comment: Thank you so much for your extremely helpful and detailed response to my question!

Answer (score 6):

Because it is not allowed to have method with same Parameter types and different return type.
So:

`public void update(String topic, String title)` and `public boolean update(String category, String theater)` has two strings as Parameter, but first one is a void and second one Returns a boolean value

Comment: You're implying the problem is the different return types, when in fact the problem is *in spite* of the different return types.

Answer (score 4):

The signature of a Java method consists of:

- method name
- the types and order of parameters (e.g. `foo(String, Date)` vs. `foo(Date, String)`)

These are *not* part of a method's signature

- return type
- names of parameters (e.g. `foo(int a, int b)` vs. `foo(int b, int a)`)

No two methods in a class may have same signature.

Comment: Perhaps a [link to the relevant section of JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) would be helpful too? :)

Comment: Thank you so much, both of you were very helpful